# Hyperlinks are not working in overleaf

Tags: overleaf, hyperlink

I wrote some statements in overleaf to generate hyperlinks. When I click on the links from the pdf after compilation those links did not work. However, if I copy and paste the links in the address bar of the browser they work well.

I follow [this](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5f66e60904795a0001c1b9d3) template from overleaf to generate my CV.

The link parts is

```
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape Jake Ryan} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small 123-456-7890 $|$ \href{mailto:x@x.com}{\underline{jake@su.edu}} $|$ 
    \href{https://linkedin.com/in/...}{\underline**{linkedin.com/in/jake}}** $|$
    \href{https://github.com/...}**{\underline{github.com/jake}}**
\end{center}
```

The highlighted portions are for linkedIn and github link. But they are not working.

What can I do so that the links work well? Any alternative for this link generation code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, you click on links in the downloaded pdf? No in the Overleaf preview on the righ part of the website.

Comment: Did you really write `https://linkedin.com/in/...` for the first argument of `\href`, or did you actually wrote the complete URL `https://linkedin.com/in/jake`?

Comment: please post code that can be tested, you just have a fragment and it has `...` and `**` so leaves everyone to guess what might be wrong in your actual document.